# Can the equivalent point weight extend beyond the body on which it acts?

Tags: statics

If the x location of the centroid equals (moment about O)/(equivalent point weight) and there are forces acting above and below the given body, couldn't the value of the x coordinate potentially extend beyond the body?

Comment: I don't really follow the wording of this.  You can definitely have a centroid (or center of mass) that is outside of the physical body, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: take a donut, the center of Mass will not be in the donation, but in the hole

Answer (score 0):

Yes. What you are doing with $ x=\frac{M_O}{W} $ is finding the moment arm of the weight. That is typically the center of mass of a body.

Reverse the equation to get $M_O = x W$, or the moment about origin depends on the moment arm of the weight $W$.

Now the part of your question that compares this $x$ with the "extent of the body" it is unclear, although logic dictates that the center of mass is *always* within the bounds of a solid body.